# How to make `SomeClass.new` to return computed value rather than created object

Tags: ruby

A bit confused about Ruby's `initialize` method.

Why does not it return my value, as other methods do?

```
class SomeClass

  attr_reader :val

  def initialize a, b, c
    @val = a + b + c
    @val
  end

end

val = SomeClass.new 1, 2, 3
```

I need `val` to be `6` not initialized object.

Of course i can use `val.val` but that's another story.

Comment: This makes no sense, `new` != `initialize`, in OOP a `new` classmethod must return the instance. Why don't you just use a classmethod if you're not interested in creating an instance of a class?

Comment: From a design standpoint this is not a good idea.  New should return a newly initialized object, doing otherwise is not obvious or intuitive to other programmers.  Of course, if nobody else will see this code, it doesn't matter... until *you* look at it three months from now and wonder what is going on in the code.

Comment: That's just an exercise and yes, i was advised to not use this on production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `self.new` method:

```
class SomeClass
  def self.new(*)
    instance = super
    instance.val
  end

  attr_reader :val

  def initialize a, b, c
    @val = a + b + c
    @val
  end

end

p SomeClass.new 1, 2, 3
#=> 6
```

When you create a instance of a class you are in fact calling `self.new` of that class which then call `initialize` method and return the initialized instance.

#### See [live demo here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=how-to-make-initialize-to-return-computed-value-rather-than-created-object.rb&run=true)

Answer (score 1):

`initialize` is a method just like any other method. *Of course*, it returns the return value, just like any other method.

What gave you the impression that it doesn't? You never call `initialize` in the code sample you provided, so how do you know what value it returns?

```
class SomeClass
  attr_reader :val

  def initialize a, b, c
    @val = a + b + c
    @val
  end

end

obj = SomeClass.allocate
val = obj.send :initialize, 1, 2, 3
# => 6
```

Comment: Thanks for nice trick! However i need `SomeClass.new` to return the value without extra callings on initialized object. I'll update the question.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. You are asking "Why does `initialize` not return my value", but I just showed you that it *does* return its value. So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, the actual question is "Why `SomeClass.new` does not return my value". Question updated a while ago.

Comment: Well, that's trivial: you haven't changed `SomeClass.new`, so why *would* it return something different?

Comment: I just rechecked the question and it *still* reads: "A bit confused about Ruby's `initialize` method.

Why does not it return my value, as other methods do?" There's no mention of `SomeClass.new` other than the title.